# when i am fetching date from excel sheet getting errors

Tags: ruby, excel

When I tried to get date from excel sheet, I get the following error:

```
 undefined method `length' for #<Date: 2011-11-11 (4911753/2,0,2299161)>
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.3/lib/watir/input_elements.rb:439:
    in `limit_to_maxlength'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.3/lib/watir/input_elements.rb:412:
    in `type_by_character'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-2.0.3/lib/watir/input_elements.rb:379:
    in `set'
    profile_check.rb:66:in `test_2'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:695:in `run'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:656:in `block (2 levels) in run_test_
    suites'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:650:in `each'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:650:in `block in run_test_suites'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:649:in `each'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:649:in `run_test_suites'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:609:in `run'
    C:/ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/minitest/unit.rb:508:in `block in autorun'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Post your code in addition to the error message.

Answer (score 0):

In the excel sheet define that column as text so it will fetch proper date as your web page format.
Because excel sheets have different date format.